# How to globally replace strings in lines NOT starting with a certain pattern

Tags: sed

I want to globally replace the string foo with the string bar, using sed. This should only be done for lines which do NOT start with the string ##Input.

I can't get it to work. I tried things like this but reached a point where I'm not sure if I know what I'm doing:

```
sed -i '/^##Input/ s/foo/bar/g' myfile
```

Please help!

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You just need to negate the match using `!`:

```
sed -i '/^##Input/! s/foo/bar/g' myfile
```

Comment: This is so useful! I didn't realize you could give sed an input that matches the line before you run the search and replace on that line. This helps me immensely!

Comment: @bballdave025: See the [addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#sed-addresses) section of the GNU `sed` manual to learn more.

Answer (score -5):

You got to escape # as in `\#`.

Comment: There's no need to escape the `#`. It has no special meaning to `sed`.

Answer (score -10):

An ugly answer for an ugly request (i.e. they get what they asked for):

```
echo \{
for file in *.json; do
    sed -n '/^[\{\}]/! s/\([^\,]\)$/\1,/; /^[\{\}]/!p' $file
done
echo \{
```

Comment: I fail to see how it's an 'ugly request' but your comment might be called that. Also it doesn't really answer the question. I mean okay it might be understandable what that means but to someone asking the question do you really think they'll understand that sed invocation? And who said anything about a json file anyway ?