# Sed regex and substring negation

Tags: regex, sed

What is the correct syntax for finding a substring (a string which is preceded and followed by specific strings) which does **not** match a specific pattern?

For example, I want to take all substrings which *start* with `BEGIN_`, *end* with `_END` and the substring in between is **not** equal to `FOO`; and replace the whole substring with the format "(*inner substring*)". The following would match:

- `BEGIN_bar_END` -> `(bar)`
- `BEGIN_buz_END` -> `(buz)`
- `BEGIN_ihfd8f398IHFf9f39_END` -> `(ihfd8f398IHFf9f39)`

But `BEGIN_FOO_END` would not match.

I have played around with the following, but cannot seem to find the correct syntax:

```
sed -e 's/BEGIN_(^FOO)_END/($1)/g'
sed -e 's/BEGIN_([^FOO])_END/($1)/g'
sed -e 's/BEGIN_(?!FOO)_END/($1)/g'
sed -e 's/BEGIN_(!FOO)_END/($1)/g'
sed -e 's/BEGIN_(FOO)!_END/($1)/g'
sed -e 's/BEGIN_!(FOO)_END/($1)/g'
```

Comment: As a note, when dealing with whole lines, this can be achieved using `!`: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-32

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There is no general negation operator in `sed`, IIRC because compilation of regexes with negation to [DFAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) takes exponential time. You can work around this with

```
'/BEGIN_FOO_END/b; s/BEGIN_\(.*\)_END/(\1)/g'
```

where `/BEGIN_FOO_END/b` means: if we find `BEGIN_FOO_END`, then **branch** (jump) to the end of the `sed` script.

Comment: could also be written `sed '/BEGIN_FOO_END/!s/BEGIN_\(.*\)_END/(\1)/g'`

Comment: I'd like to note that `sed '/BEGIN_FOO_END/!s|BEGIN_\(.*\)_END|(\1)|g'` works but `sed '|BEGIN_FOO_END|!s|BEGIN_\(.*\)_END|(\1)|g'` does not! Evidently, it lets you substitute a different separator than "/" in the latter section, but not in the first section. Weird.

Comment: @CommaToast The `s///` command can use an arbitrary delimiter; addresses cannot.

Comment: Address delimiters *can* be arbitrary, but the first delimiter must be escaped, eg:  `printf '%s\n' a b c | sed '\|a|,\|b|d`' - tested with GNU sed with the `--posix` option.

Comment: Kudos for the DFA link!

Answer (score 35):

This topic may be old, but for the sake of completeness, what about the negation operator `!` :

Make all unhappy become VERY HAPPY :

```
echo -e 'happy\nhappy\nunhappy\nhappy' | sed '/^happy/! s/.*/VERY HAPPY/'
```

Found this here : [How to globally replace strings in lines NOT starting with a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953738/how-to-globally-replace-strings-in-lines-not-starting-with-a-certain-pattern#answer-4953824)

Comment: I always go to the grymoire after I see something related to sed. I checked yours and there it was, right under my nose

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you:

```
sed 'h;s/BEGIN_\(.*\)_END/(\1)/;/^(FOO)$/g' file
```

This only works if there is only one string per line.

For multiple strings per line:

```
sed 's/BEGIN_\([^F][^_]*\|F[^O][^_]*\|FO[^O][^_]*\|FOO[^_]\+\)_END/\(\1\)/g' file
```

Or the more easily understood:

```
sed 's/\(BEGIN_\)FOO\(_END\)/\1\n\2/g;s/BEGIN_\([^\n_]*\)_END/(\1\)/g;s/\n/FOO/g' file
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a pretty way, but you could always do this:

```
$ cat file
BEGIN_FOO_END
BEGIN_FrOO_END
BEGIN_rFOO_END
$ sed '/BEGIN_FOO_END/ !{s/BEGIN_\([^_]*\)_END/(\1)/}' file 
BEGIN_FOO_END
(FrOO)
(rFOO)
```