# Remove text other than the specific search string using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

Example :

Filename : *testest*

```
cat testest
```

> ```
> asd ddd asd fgg
> ert tttt ert
> asss    ffff
> asd asd ff
> ```

Search string : *asd*

Desired output :

> ```
> asd asd
> asd asd
> ```

Comment: Please show a little more effort in formatting before asking questions :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky because there's no general way of expressing `'not pattern'` in sed. More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053100/sed-regex-and-substring-negation). However, you can express not asd like this: `/\(\b\([^a]..\|.[^s].\|..[^d]\|\S\{1,2\}\|\S\{4,\}\)\b\)`

So removing them looks like this:  `sed -e 's/\(\b\([^a]..\|.[^s].\|..[^d]\|\S\{1,2\}\|\S\{4,\}\)\b\)/ /g'`. I.e. doesn't start with a, 2nd letter isn't s, 3rd letter isn't d. Also, not shorter, neither longer than 3 chars.

But you'll have multiple white spaces so you'll have to remove them too: `sed -e 's/\s\+/ /g'`

So, a one-liner:  `sed -e 's/\(\b\([^a]..\|.[^s].\|..[^d]\|\S\{1,2\}\|\S\{4,\}\)\b\)/ /g' -e 's/\s\+/ /g'`

Imho you rather do it with perl because that supports negative lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

For the details you've provided, the following might be just fine:

```
arr=()
while IFS=: read -r n w; do
    if [[ "${arr[n]}" ]]; then
        w=" $w"
    fi

    arr[n]="${arr[n]}$w"

done < <(grep -ohn "asd" input_file)

printf '%s\n' "${arr[@]}"
```

If there are more constraints on the input ( it is very large, for example ), consider using a different, faster solution. `awk` might be the right tool for the task.

---

Let's test it ( script name is ***sof*** )

input_file:

```
asd ddd asd fgg
ert tttt ert
asss    ffff
asd asd ff
```

Output:

```
./sof
asd asd
asd asd
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data

```
cat test.log
asd ddd asd fgg
ert tttt ert
asss    ffff
asd asd ff
asd asd asd
```

#Script

```
    while read line
    do
    echo $line |grep -o asd |xargs

    done <test.log |grep .
```

## Execution result

```
   ./main
    asd asd
    asd asd
    asd asd asd
```