# Matching negative and positive pattern in one sed

Tags: regex, linux, sed, regex-negation, regex-group

I have a problem with making sed command, which gonna change lines, where `=sometext=` occurs and change it to another pattern, but will not do it when `https` occcurs in that line. I have no idea how I should change this command:`sed -i 's/=\([^=]*\)=/{{\1}}/g'`

Comment: similar question with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053100/sed-regex-and-substring-negation

Comment: Maybe something like `awk '!/https/ && /=sometext=/{gensub(/=([^=]*)=/, "\1", $0)}1' file` with gawk. Can't test now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to read the sed manual about matching lines: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html chapter 4:

> The following command replaces the word ‘hello’ with ‘world’ only in lines *not* containing the word ‘apple’:
>
> ```
> sed '/apple/!s/hello/world/' input.txt > output.txt
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple blocks, e.g.:

```
sed '/=sometext=/ { /https/b; s/.../.../; }'
```