# How to replace an unknown IP address in a specific line of a text file

Tags: linux, sed

How can I apply this sed command to a specific line in a text file instead of to the entire file?

I found a solution here for replacing any IP addresses in a file with a specific address.   I need to apply this command to a specific line in the file so that it only replaces one single unknown IP address.  I saw that sed uses -n to filter but I literally know nothing about how to apply this to achieve my goal.

This code works for every IP in the file:

```
sed -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/x.x.x.x/g' test.txt
```

How can I apply it to the only line in the file that also includes the string, "ipv4" so that other lines containing IP addresses are left unmodified?

Comment: The `-n` flag will suppress the output. Usually it's used with the 'p' command to print specific lines.

Comment: To state the obvious, that only works for IPv4 addresses. It breaks for IPv6 addresses.

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output to get the best help.

Answer (score 1):

With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), you can use a regex as an [address](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses-overview) like this:

```
sed -re '/ipv4/s/[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}/x.x.x.x/g' test.txt
```

If you don't specify `-r`, you'll need to escape the braces, i.e.:

```
sed -e '/ipv4/s/[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}.[0-9]\{1,3\}/x.x.x.x/g' test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for that.  So adding /ipv4/ at the beginning of the command will only replace the IP on the one line that also includes the string ipv4?    The full line is: "bind-address-ipv4": "x.x.x.x",

Comment: @DocCaliban exactly! Just adapt this pattern to fulfil your need

Comment: @DocCaliban: Does that work for you? Do you use `-e` or `-E` or `-r`?

Comment: That's not working for me.  I am using -e  If I leave out the /ipv4/ the overall command works by changing all IP addresses in the file.  Still trying to target just the one line.

Comment: @DocCaliban: Sorry missed that one. You'll need to specify the `-r` flag to use extended regular expressions. Alternatively, you'll need to escape the braces.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip over uninteresting lines:

```
sed '/ipv4/!b;s/YOUR PATTERN HERE/YOUR IP HERE/' input
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you want to find the first occurrence of the ip address on a line that also contains `ipv4`, and skip all other occurrences.

With GNU [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), try

```
sed -i -E '/ipv4/{s/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}/x.x.x.x/g;T;:a;n;ba}' test.txt
```

The `-E` will enable POSIX ERE syntax, no need to escape `{}` and `()`. The `-i` will replace inline in the file directly. `/ipv4/` will find a line with `ipv4` on it, and then `{s/[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}/x.x.x.x/g;T;:a;n;ba}` will do the replacement only on that line.  See [potong's explanation of the `T;:a;n;ba` here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56212401/11329890)

If you have a POSIX `sed`, try

```
sed -e '/ipv4/ {' -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}/x.x.x.x/g' -e ':a' -e n -e 'ba' -e '}' file > newfile
```

Comment: Thanks!  When I try that I get an unterminated { error, but I don't see a problem in the code.

Comment: @DocCaliban Interesting, I just [tested](https://ideone.com/RZzuzF) this code and it looks working, i.e. it replaces the first occurrence of the IP on a line having `ipv4` substring. Do you have a GNU sed? Are you using variables?

Comment: @DocCaliban  As it has been pointed out by Wiktor, the code is not causing errors, kindly please check your code. Share the exact code you are using if possible.

Comment: Hello.  I must be using a version of sed that is not cooperating.  It's whatever comes with my QNAP NAS.

Comment: @DocCaliban Sorry, no idea what version of `sed` is used there. Try these two: 1) `sed '/ipv4/{s/[0-9]\{1,3\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}/x.x.x.x/g;T;:a;n;ba}' file` or 2) `sed -e '/ipv4/ {' -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}/x.x.x.x/g' -e T -e ':a' -e n -e 'ba' -e '}'  file`. If neither works, try `sed -e '/ipv4/ {' -e 's/[0-9]\{1,3\}\(\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\)\{3\}/x.x.x.x/g' -e ':a' -e n -e 'ba' -e '}' file` which is a bit less precise, but seems to work in POSIX mode.