# Printing alias from ~/.ssh/config— with or without trailing hyphen

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, ssh-config

I have following file, it's a config file for ssh.

```
Host vps2 # Linode
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user

Host vps3 # Vultr
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user   

Host vps4
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user

Host vps5
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user 

Host vps6
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user 

Host vps7 # DigitalOcean
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user

Host vps8 # GCP
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user   

Host pi
   HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
   User pi

# OLD SHALL NOT BE USED

Host vps13
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user

Host vps14-old
   HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
   User foo_user 

Host vps4-old
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user 

Host vps15-old
   HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
   User foo_user 

Host vps11-old
    HostName xxx.xx.xx.xxx
    User foo_user
```

I need to print alias that start with `vps*`, below (copied) snippets will exactly do that.

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^vps/){print $i}}}' $HOME/.ssh/config
vps2
vps3
vps4
vps5
vps6
vps7
vps8
vps3-old
vps4-old
vps5-old
vps11-old
```

Now I want to print all alias that has no `-old` suffix, adding `| grep -v old` works.

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^vps/){print $i}}}' $HOME/.ssh/config | grep -v "old"
vps2
vps3
vps4
vps5
vps6
vps7
vps8
```

Is there any cleaner way ? Preferably involving only 1 tools, I tried playing with `awk`  command to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `$i!~/-old$/` condition to the `awk` command:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^vps/ && $i!~/-old$/){print $i}}}' ~/.ssh/config
```

(Note: I prefer `~` over `$HOME` when it's not in double-quotes, just in case of weird characters in the path.)

Comment: Thanks, I can combine this with `ORS` to get the result in one line.

Comment: That would fail if the input file contained `User vpsmith` for example as it'd output `vpsmith` as a host name.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sed`, which has a grep-like mode if you use `-n` (no print) that supports a more extended regex than `grep`. The trick for filtering out lines ending in `-old` is found here: [Sed regex and substring negation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053100/2988730):

```sh
sed -n "/-old/b; s/^Host\s\+\(vps\S*\)\s*\(#.*\)\?/\1/p" $HOME/.ssh/config
```

The inverse (including `-old`) is a bit simpler, since it only requires positive matches:

```sh
sed -n "s/^Host\s\+\(vps\S*-old\)\s*\(#.*\)\?/\1/p" $HOME/.ssh/config
```

Comment: What if I want to only print alias which has `-old` suffix ?

Comment: Then you remove the first command `/-old/b;` and add `-old` to the first capture group a the end, just like `vps` is at the beginning.

Comment: @Liso. I spelled it out in the update

Comment: Actually I figured that out, but seeing I need the result parsed in single line (which I have not specified in my original question), [`awk` is much simpler.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15580184/12289283)

Comment: I can't (entirely) disagree with awk being simpler :)

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for `\s` and `\+` (and maybe also `\?`, I'm not sure about that one). Since it requires GNU sed anyway you could make it more concise by adding `-E` to enable EREs and then removing many of the backslashes. Btw a good rule of thumb is to always use single quotes around shell strings, including scripts, and only use double quotes or no quotes when you have a specific NEED for the shell to do some interpretation on the string/script.

Comment: @EdMorton. Good call on the quotes. That's what happens when I copy and paste from another post :) I'll look into the rest later and fix it

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/-old/!s/^Host\s*(vps\S*).*/\1/p' file
```

Turn off implicit printing and on extended regexps by using the `-n` and `-E` options.

If a line does not contain `-old`, match on a line beginning `Host` followed by some whitespace, followed by `vps`, followed by zero or more non-whitespace, followed by anything and replace it by `vps` followed by any non-whitespace and print the result.

To only show lines with `-old` in them, use:

```
sed -En '/-old/s/^Host\s*(vps\S*).*/\1/p' file
```

N.B. This relies on `Host` lines not containing comments or more than one host name.

Answer (score 1):

Idk why you're looping when the string you want is always in the 2nd field of a line that starts with `Host`:

```
$ awk '/^Host vps/ && !/-old/{ print $2 }' file
vps2
vps3
vps4
vps5
vps6
vps7
vps8
vps13
```

I see in comments you actually want the output all on 1 line, that'd be:

```
$ awk '/^Host vps/ && !/-old/{ printf "%s%s", sep, $2; sep=OFS } END{print ""}' file
vps2 vps3 vps4 vps5 vps6 vps7 vps8 vps13
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po '(?<=Host )vps\d+(?!-old)' file | sort -uV
```

Comment: You need a bunch of caveats if you're going to suggest `-P`

Comment: @MadPhysicist What caveats exactly?

Comment: GNU grep, not sure minimum version.

Comment: That's obvious.