# in sed, how to do a pattern substitution only when another pattern doesn't exist

Tags: vim, awk, sed, csh

In sed, how can I do pattern replacement when a line doesn't contain certain pattern?
I know how to do it in vi or vim.
For example, to replace 'rabbit' to 'hare' when the line does not contain 'animal', I can do

```
:g!/animal/s/rabbit/hare/g
```

I want to do the same thing for hundreds of files under a directory using foreach, find and sed.  When the line does not contain '= (Dtype)', I want to replace 'Dtype val1 = expression;' to 'Dtype val1 = (Dtype)(expression);'.  But excluding cases like 'Dtype *pval = expression;'. That is, I want to put (Dtype) casting for non-pointer assignments. I tried

```
>foreach i (`find . -name \*.c`)
? sed -e 'g!/ = (Dtype)/s/Dtype \([a-z].*\) = \(.*\);/Dtype \1 = (Dtype)(\2);/g' $i >! tmp
? mv tmp $i
? end
```

But this 'g!/pattern/s/patter1/pattern2/g' doesn't work in sed. What's the correct command?

Comment: @Sundeep Hi, your reference is in the Documentation. How can I search for it? separately in the Documentation section?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to globally replace strings in lines NOT starting with a certain pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953738/how-to-globally-replace-strings-in-lines-not-starting-with-a-certain-pattern)

Comment: dunno about search leading to that documentation reference, but the first link I got when search online with exact question title solves your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/animal/!s/rabbit/hare/g' file
```

Search for `animal` and if it is not found replace `rabbit` by `hare` globally.

Comment: What is GNU specific here?

Comment: Thanks, actually I knew the answer but couldn't find the answer the other day on stackoverflow, so put a question so that others can get help from it. :)